# Graph Theory (Prove that a a simple graph and its complement cannot both be disconnected)

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that a a simple graph and its complement cannot both be disconnected.

My answer:
Suppose that a simple graph and its complement can both be disconnected. Let $A =$ simple graph and $A^{c} =$ its complement. Since A is simple there is no loops neither multi-edges which implies that in $A^{c}$ we allow loops and multi-edges. But since both are disconnected it means that $A^{c}$ is not the complement of A thus we have a contradiction.

Comment: "which implies that in $A^c$ we allow loops and multi-edges" ... errr, what?

Comment: Doesn't that mean that in a simple graph we don't have loops and multi-edges but since it is the complement of it, it must contain a loop and multi-edges?

Comment: The complement of a simple graph seems to be in this context a simple graph (with the basic rule that $v$ and $w$ are connected in $A^c$ if and only if $v$ and $w$ are not connected in $A$, with $v \not=w$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $G$ is disconnected, say $A_1,A_2\dots,A_m$ be the connected components of $G$, now take any two vertices $v_1$ and $v_2$ of $G^{c}$, if it's in the same connected component of $G$ then in the graph $G^{c}$ we will get an edge from $v_1$ to some vertex of a different path component and from there we will get an edge to $v_2$ hence they are connected in $G^{c}$ , also if two vertices are in different path components of $G$ then it is clearly connected in $G^{c}$, hence our result follows!